# Using string format for Url.Content doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this little foreach statement in an ASPX page:

```
<%
foreach(string path in pathList)
{
%>
   <img src="<%=Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/Images/{0}", path))%>" />
<%
}
%>
```

I want that to display all images using `Url.Content` from the list of paths.

But my code doesn't work.

In the generated HTML, the above code returns me `<img src='/Content/Images/' />` instead of `<img src='/Content/Images/page.png' />` and others.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that `path` actually contains "page.png"?

Comment: And have you checked that the number of `<img>` elements created is the same as the length of the pathList? But they all get same same `src`?

Comment: The function which returns a list (associated to `pathList`) without `.` symbol, like as `pagepng` instead `page.png`. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the tag

```
 <img src="<%=Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/Images/{0}", path)) %>" />
```

ALso, are you sure the the path really has the value of 'page.png' ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a `.` in my function code ... That's was my problem